# Xamarin Forms and WCF NetTcpBinding with duplex

Tags: wcf, xamarin, nettcpbinding

I have developed a self-hosted WPF server application and a client WPF application which communicated with WCF NetTcpBinding with duplex like common connected TCP socket communication scenario.

Now, I will develop a mobile client which communicates existing self-hosted WPF server application.

I know that old Xamarin does not support NetTcpBinding.

Does the latest Xamarin Forms (or Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS) support NetTcpBinding with duplex? It seems that .NET Core 3.0 supports NetTcpBinding, but I have no idea for Xamarin.

If Xamarin does not support WCF NetTcpBinding, is self-hosted SignalR a good alternative for full duplex connected communication?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Dotnet Core3.0 SDK supports the Nettcpbinding and I can generate the client proxy class properly by using Microsoft WCF web service reference provider. Thereby it supports duplex communication too.
[image]
I didn’t have much exposure to Xamarin. If the project based on the Core 3.0 SDK. I think it should be capable of supporting Nettcpbinding.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you for checking on .NET Core 3.0